# How sed inserted when matching template 2 times a replacement?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

```
echo'</ns:epsIndividualDefaultContextId<ns:epsIndividualContextId>100</ns:epsIndividualContextId>' | sed's/<\/ns:epsIndividualContextId>/<ns:epsIndividualContextId<\/ns:epsIndividualContextId>/'
```

Result:

```
</ns:epsIndividualDefaultContextId><ns:epsIndividualContextId>100<ns:epsIndividualContextId></ns:epsIndividualContextId>
```

How to replace a certain amount of time? Example 2 times.

To the outlet turned out:

```
</ns:epsIndividualDefaultContextId><ns:epsIndividualContextId>100<ns:epsIndividualContextId></ns:epsIndividualContextId><ns:epsIndividualContextId></ns:epsIndividualContextId>
```

Comment: I've heard that on some versions you could do `s/pattern/replace/fromOccurence,toOccurence`, but that doesn't work on my GNU sed. An easy way to do so would be to replace the first occurence twice, i.e. `echo $data | sed 's/pattern/replace' | sed 's/pattern/replace/'`

Comment: @Aaron you can use `sed -e EXPR -e EXPR` rather than piping two commands.

Comment: Please post the expected output with a sample input neatly formatted

Comment: Also, there is an answer on unix.stackexchange which may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155805/sed-replace-first-k-instances-of-a-word-in-the-file

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please [edit] your question to use a much briefer example, e.g. with `a` and `b` for the regexp and replacement string, so what you want to do isn't hidden among hundreds of irrelevant characters. Everyone's answers are getting downvoted and deleted because it's so hard to see in your question what you actually want to do.

Answer (score -1):

use 'g' at the end of the sed statement to replace all matched occurence. but to replace same string multiple time you have to use sed that no. of times like below.

For two times replacement

```
echo'</ns:epsIndividualDefaultContextId<ns:epsIndividualContextId>100</ns:epsIndividualContextId>' | sed's/<\/ns:epsIndividualContextId>/<ns:epsIndividualContextId<\/ns:epsIndividualContextId>/' | sed's/<\/ns:epsIndividualContextId>/<ns:epsIndividualContextId<\/ns:epsIndividualContextId>/'
```

Hope this might work

Comment: And if I need to add a 100 times? 100 prescribing patterns?)

Comment: then use awk instead sed

Comment: and can be used AWK

Answer (score -3):

You can use:

```
echo whole_string | sed "s/string_to_find/string_to_insert/g"
```

This will find **string_to_find** as many times as it can be found in **whole_string**.

Comment: And if I need to add a 100 times? 100 prescribing patterns?)